# API PHP to JSON Output Error

Tags: php, arrays, json, client-server

So,
Am working on an API that appears to work quite well on-server. I formed the array sequence in PHP and finished with json_encode($stuff),json_pretty_print.

```
echo '<pre>'.json_encode(thefez), json_pretty_print).'</pre>';
```

On-server it echos perfectly. If I type in the [url directly from any browser](http://api.mutrs.me/?imos&volume=1), can see the data. 
I added a var_dump to check.

Client-Side with json_decode: Returns **NULL**:

```
$thanks=json_decode(file_get_contents('http://api.mutrs.me/?imos&volume=1'));

var_dump($thanks);
```

Client-Side without json_decode: Returns **DATA**:

```
$thanks=(file_get_contents('http://api.mutrs.me/?imos&volume=1');

var_dump($thanks);

{
"muid": "IM5LGM02MFS8RJLKGY9W",
"bandname": "Marbles For Zen",
"core": {
    "joined": "Sun 01 March 2015",
    "bandbio": "Zen And Marbles",
    "genre": "Rhythm Blues",
    "subgenre": "Dixie Rhythm"
},
```

However, using either, when attempting to extract the data, using **foreach**, off-server, am getting an invalid argument error.

**UPDATE**
So, after pulling the **pre** tags, the decode w/ foreach() seems to work.
The bug seems to be when the read reaches the first set of **[ ]**, where it outputs Array, Array, Array. Why this would happen?

```
'muid'=>$id,
'title'=> $title,
'about'=>[
     'product'=>$product,
     'mediatype'=>$mediatype,
     'scrib'=>$scrib,
        ],
```

Comment: Try loosing the `json_pretty_print` option and the `<pre>` and `</pre>` once you have proved it works you dont need them and they in fact break the json data structure

Comment: `<pre>` tags are not valid JSON.  Lose the `<pre>` tags.

Comment: Right, the **pre** was just for effect. i removed it but still a **foreach** error.

Comment: I ran `json_decode(file_get_contents('http://api.mutrs.me/?imos&volume=1'))` on my computer and it worked fine.

Comment: What do you see if you `var_dump(json_last_error())`?

Comment: Rocket, did you use a foreach() after decoding? This is where my error is. The var_dump() works both ways.

Comment: Maybe you should `json_decode(..., TRUE)`?  The 2nd parameter tells to convert all objects into associative arrays.  P.S. You said in your question that your `var_dump` "Returns NULL", did you not?

Comment: Yes, at first run, it did return NULL, which I believe was because of the **pre** tag. After removing, the decode worked.  As for the json_last_error am only getting **int(0)**.

Comment: var_dump will still render the html, so your json is actually `html+json+html`, and will FAIL with a json syntax error, since `<pre>` is not json.

Comment: When you try to echo an array as a string it prints `"Array"`.

Comment: Rocket, the issue came down to the ability to separate each array after the closing brace and before the next opening brace   } {   When I did a single parameter and echoed the decoded result it showed 2 items. Perfect. But when I go to parse them in foreach it throws the invalid argument error. I did a workaround and now it is looping strangely.

Answer (score 0):

**Resolved**

So the issue seems to be 99% resolved. The problem actually began in the structuring of the php arrays for json output, as you can see the difference from the original code and that below. By wrapping the entire cluster into an array, it [bracketed] and the arrays within ordered accordingly.

Server-side:

```
$mez[]=array(
$mez["muid"]=$id,
$mez["bandname"]=$bandname,
$mez["core"]=array(
            'joined'=>$since,
            'bandbio'=>$bio,
            'genre'=>$genre,
            'subgenre'=> $subgenre
              ),
);

}
echo json_encode(array($mez));
```

Client-side:

```
$connection=json_decode(file_get_contents('http://api.mutrs.me/artists/'));
foreach($connection as $data) {

$id=$data->muid;
$band=$data->bandname;

echo $id.'<br>'.$band.'';
}
```